# Xcode changed MinuteCalendarUnit to NSCalendarUnitMInute. How do I change my statement?

Tags: swift, nscalendar

This morning, my program compiles with errors. This is the message:

> MinuteCalendarUnit was deprecated in iOS version 8.0 Use NSCalendarUnitMInute instead

How would I reconstruct this statement?

```
let comp = calendar.components((.HourCalendarUnit | .MinuteCalendarUnit) | .SecondCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can replace by:

```
let comp = calendar.components((NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute) | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
```

Comment: Thank you! You made me eliminate the last 2 warnings from my project :)